# Position a list according to one of it's children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `nav` with 3 children, a first list, an image and a second list, I want to center the image and have the lists around it. I made a [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/x3p5Lmzzwb) for visualisation as I'm using it in my project
Thank you for the help

I tried using `justify-center` on the parent (`nav`), obviously it doesn't work because the lists do not have the same size, so the egg will never be in the middle.
I tried giving the `nav` a fixed width and center it with an auto margin X, I think it's the best solution but I didn't get it working
I tried centering with `justify-center` then adding a margin on the right the size of the image's `div` but apparently that was the dumbest attempt because I really thought it would work and it really does not lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `grid` on `nav`, just like:

```
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 120px 1fr;
}
```

See If this is what you want.